# SQL - Datediff between two closest dates

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I have two tables. Let's call the first one A and the other B.
A is:

| ID | Doc ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1a | 1-Jan-2020 |
| 1 | 1a | 1-Feb-2020 |
| 1 | 1b | 1-Mar-2020 |
| 2 | 1a | 1-Jan-2020 |

B is:

| ID | Doc2 ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2a | 1-Mar-2020 |
| 1 | 2a | 1-Apr-2020 |
| 2 | 2b | 1-Feb-2020 |
| 2 | 2a | 1-Mar-2020 |

Now using SQL, I want to create a table which has all the values in Table A and the difference between the date in table A and the closest date in table B. For eg. 1-Jan-2020 should be subtracted from 1-Mar-2020 and similarly, 1-Feb-2020 should be subtracted from 1-Mar-2020. Can you please help me with it?

Tables Image:
[image]

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using? I have removed the conflicting tags; [edit] your question to retag the one you are actually asking about.  Also, what does the above have to do about [[tag:databricks]]? You make no reference to it in the question.

Comment: I am not sure what RDBMS databricks uses... I am writing the code in azure databricks using %sql in databricks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateDiff` in the SQL to achieve this.

The below code may work for your requirement:

```
SELECT A.id,B.id as table2id, A.DocID, Abs(DateDiff(Day, A.dat, B.dat)) as diff_days,A.dat as table1date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.dat ORDER BY Abs(DateDiff(Day, A.dat, B.dat)) ASC) as closerank,
B.dat as table2date from A,B where A.dat!=B.dat;
```

You can find the closest date for every date in Table A by arranging the `DateDiff` between two tables in an ascending order by using `ROW_NUMBER`.

**Output:**

[image]

Refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) to learn more `Datediff` in SQL.

Comment: Getting this error: Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Day`' given input columns

Comment: In Databricks it is working fine for me. Day is a keyword in that function. If you are using databricks once close the workspace and open it again. If you still facing issuess please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also, try with this sample code in another cell in databricks. If that results same, then try with another cluster in the databricks. ```SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, '2017-10-10', '2019-08-21') AS column1;```

Comment: Hey @Mufeez, did the suggestion work? do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot.